# mysql select users without cards in statuses A, B AND with status C

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to return users who have cards in status C BUT no cards in statuses A, B.

Current query returns me record who has C but they also have B! I want to get null in such case.

```
SELECT u.*,
   b.id AS categories, 
   c.id AS cards
FROM users AS u
       JOIN categories AS b ON u.id = b.user_id      
       JOIN cards AS gac ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE b.type = 'whatever' AND
      c.status NOT IN ('A', 'B') AND c.status = 'C';
```

In ruby on rails:

```
users = User.includes(categories: :cards).where(categories: {type: :whatever}).where.not(cards: {status: ['A', 'B']}).where(cards: {status: 'C'})
```

So if they have cards in [A, B] and also C, I don't want to have the user returned!!!

Comment: Question is that, can a single record have both status on them? I am not quite clear on the question

Comment: `c.status NOT IN ('A', 'B') AND c.status = 'C'` strange condition

Comment: no, only one status per card @YuriiVerbytskyi

Answer (score 0):

In the WHERE clause use a subquery which returns the `user_id`s that meet the conditions you want to apply:

```
SELECT u.*,
   b.id AS categories, 
   c.id AS cards
FROM users AS u
JOIN categories AS b ON u.id = b.user_id      
JOIN cards AS c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE b.type = 'whatever'
AND u.id IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM cards 
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING SUM(status IN ('A', 'B')) = 0 AND SUM(status = 'C') > 0
)
```

Comment: could you write that in RoR too?

Comment: I can't help you with Ruby, only with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` conditions are applied to each row, not the set.  So your current condition is just filtering out rows that don't have `c.status = 'C'`.

What you want to do is identify users that have rows with `status = 'C'`, then filter out users that also have a record with `status IN ('A','B')`.  One way is to use a subquery:

```
WHERE c.status = 'C'
AND c.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM cards WHERE status IN ('A',B'))
```